Raising floor before laminates. OSB or Plywood?
I am needing to raise my hallway and 2 room floors to match my kitchen that has been tiled. There was already a difference but I need to raise in total 4cm. 15mm will be my underlay and laminates but the remaining 25mm I would need to use either plywood or OSB.
I was wondering is there any recommendation on which one to use or not to use or if I should mix - i.e. do 18mm of OSB then 6mm of plywood, or something similar?

For the flooring, it does not really matter that much.  Usually the decision is based more on cost.  Some types of plywood does better if it gets wet than OSB, but low use for rooms not kitchen/bathroom.

Ah so this is hallway and living rooms so I’m guessing OSB will be fine since it shouldn’t really be getting wet etc? Am I understanding that correct? :)

Yes.  Usually those rooms might get wet if in a basement, but other than that it is more of a cost decision/personal feelings(like plywood, like OSB) which to use.

Thank you very much! Super helpful :)
